# Use regex to match indicators (a) (b) and so on

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of speeches, and I want to remove all those speeches that contain a bullet point indicator among (a)..(z), (A)..(Z) and (i)...(ix). I cannot find the correct regex match to include all these possibilities. I tried without success with:

`list = [item for item in list if '(\w)' in item]`

Should I do them one by one or is there a more efficient way?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to use the `re` module. `"(\w)" in item` looks for the literal string `"(\w)"` in `item`.

Comment: please provide a sample input and expected response

Comment: My list is as follows `list=['this is the first (a) sentence', 'this is the second (b) sentence', 'this is the third sentence']` I want to eliminate all list elements that contain expressions like (a) and (b) and so on, so to restitute  `list=['this is the third sentence']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do this:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r"^(\(\w\)|\([ivx]+\)).*", re.MULTILINE)

list = [item for item in list if not rx.match(item)]
```

> See the [re library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) for more information.

Comment: There's no need for `.*` in the regexp. You're not trying to match the whole string, just the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

First, to do a regex match, you need the `re` module (or [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)). You also need to take care of special tokens in regex, in this case, the parentheses.

Here's a sample regex that works:

```
re.search(r"\(([A-Za-z]|v?i{1,3}|i[vx])\)", item)
```

The above regex will cover (A) to (Z), (a) to (z), as well as (i), (ii), ... (viii), (ix).